# How to make a Check Button? (hidden checkbox with label as a button: CSS only)

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox, input

Using [method 1 to create a clickable label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6293626/1326147), [hiding the checkbox with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18078908/1326147) and [toggling it and the label with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4177175/1326147), I got this:

```js
$('label').click(function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  var cbx = $('input', this);
  cbx.prop('checked', !cbx.prop("checked"));
  console.log($('input', this).prop('checked'));
  return false;
})
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {visibility: hidden;position: absolute}
label {background-color: pink;border: 1px solid lightblue;padding: 20px}
label.active {background-color: lightgreen}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" checked />Check Button</label>
```

[Check the console for the checkbox status]

My question is: is it possible to **do the same only using CSS**?

I realize I'm using `<label>` not `<button>` and I assume there are better ways to achieve this with jQuery. If you consider replying with one, please do it using a checkbox (or at least explain why you must not use it).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try css pseudo code:

```css
input.chk-btn {
  display: none;
}
input.chk-btn + label {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background: ghoswhite;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
input.chk-btn:not(:checked) + label:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px;
}
input.chk-btn + label:active,
input.chk-btn:checked + label {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px inset;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id='c1' class='chk-btn' />
<label for='c1'>Check Button</label>
<input type="checkbox" id='c2' class='chk-btn' />
<label for='c2'>Toggle</label>
```

Comment: Appreciated, here's a [fiddle with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/ry7qdjnt/) just for showing it's working. Fancy buttons btw :P

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

Or try this:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1-1" class="regular-checkbox" /><label for="checkbox-1-1"></label>
```

**CSS**

.regular-checkbox {
        display: none;
    }

```
.regular-checkbox + label {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border: 1px solid #cacece;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    padding: 9px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.regular-checkbox + label:active, .regular-checkbox:checked + label:active {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.regular-checkbox:checked + label {
    background-color: #e9ecee;
    border: 1px solid #adb8c0;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 15px 10px -12px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    color: #99a1a7;
}

.regular-checkbox:checked + label:after {
    content: '\2714';
    font-size: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 3px;
    color: #99a1a7;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tz4u38t3/

Comment: Thanks, the [codepen link](http://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/BiHzp) you provided looks good, but what I really wanted was a checkbutton. Arvind gave the solution 1 minute after your answer.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. Please include the relevant parts of your answer here to enhance our community and avoid link-rot.